# Shell regular expression to escape the beginning and ending of a quote

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a file called "query.sql" containing an SQL query such as:

```
select * from myTable where myVar='hello' and stuff=123;
```

Currently, my bash script (in the same directory) uses that query by calling the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
query=$(<query.sql)
```

Now, I would like (either in the same line, or in a new line as follows) parse that query to escape quotes in a begin/end fashion. This is important as I am not simply replacing every quote by, say, a backslash+quote. The beginning quote gets a different treatment than the ending quote. Here is what the desired result should be (I double checked, although it is weird this is in fact the order I need those quotes in):

```
select * from myTable where myVar='\'hello\'' and stuff=123;
```

So far, I came up with the following but it doesn't work :

```
q2="${query//'([^']*)'/'\'$1\''}"
```

There are two potential problems: my $1 syntax might not be the correct way to insert the match, but more importantly (I tried hard-coding that part) the overall script seems not to work. I tried escaping the backslashes by doubling them but that didn't help either...

Comment: What's your actual goal here? To generate a shell script? If you just want to pass the contents of your file as a literal argument, you don't need to do any kind of regex-based quoting or escaping at all, and so should probably be revising the question to address the actual immediate problem this approach is *intended* to solve.

Comment: BTW, the canonical way to get an `eval`-safe quoted version is `printf -v query_q '%q' "$query"`, after which point you can run, say, `bash -c "echo $query_q"` and not worry about a `$(touch /tmp/i-pwned-you)` somewhere in your query being executed -- but that emits a string that's only safe to use in contexts where it's going to be parsed as part of a shell script, and generally, such contexts should be avoided in favor of passing data out-of-band from code (which bash, in general, makes easy!).

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for participating. I am sending these commands through ssh and this is the way to escape quotes. The whole process is pretty much done and most of the platform is out of my hands anyway so changing the process to another (better) way of doing things is out of my control. However, I am pretty sure that someone with better knowledge than mine on regexps and/or sed could help me out ;)

Comment: The `printf %q` approach I gave you works great when sending commands over ssh. And if you'd made it clear in the question that send over SSH *was* your goal, I could have added a full, direct and tested answer.

Comment: That is to say, `ssh somehost "echo $query_q"`, with `query_q` generated from `query` as I described above, will work correctly (well, as correctly as the remote `echo` implementation permits) with all possible `query` values, so long as the remote shell is bash (whether or not in POSIX mode); with `ssh somehost 'bash -i' <<EOF`, `echo $query_q` and `EOF`, it would work regardless of the default remote shell. And you can change from `echo` to whatever other command you like.

Comment: Charles, as much as I appreciate your help (and I really do, thanks again), I believe I clearly stated my goal as parsing a string in order to replace certain parts of it. I now believe I was on the wrong route using bash string manipulation, and sKwa's answer put me on the right path in using sed. What I actually want to do with that (the end-goal) is not just sending it to ssh and goes way beyond the scope of a s/o question, so I tried to keep it simple and the answer chosen does just that. But if I ever do redesign the way this command is used I will be happy to use your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution to use in external tools like a `sed` or `awk`(so it will work with `sh`,`dash`, e.t.c), it's more portable(as a good practice - use `sh` syntax with `Bash` where it possible).

```
$ cat /tmp/query.sql
select * from myTable where myVar='hello' and stuff=123;

$ sed "s:'\(\w\+\)':\'\\\'\1\\\'\':" < /tmp/query.sql                
select * from myTable where myVar='\'hello\'' and stuff=123;

# quote function
quote ()
{
    local quoted="${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}";
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}

$ quote "$(cat /tmp/query.sql)"
'select * from myTable where myVar='\''hello'\'' and stuff=123;'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On my end I was working on something and I seemed to make it work with something simpler, can you tell me what you think ?
q2=$(sed 's_'\''\([^'\'']*\)'\''_\\'\''\1\\\'\'''\''_' query.sql)

Comment: sorry wrong copy/paste:
q2=$(sed 's_'\''\([^'\'']*\)'\''_'\''\\'\''\1\\\'\'''\''_g' query.sql)

Comment: I got error: `... invalid reference \1 ..`, but I can understand what you trying to achieve and its will be much more better that `'\(\w\+\)'` regexp.

Comment: sKwa, actually i got put off by the function, but now I understand that you showed 2 different ways of solving the problem. I like the first one best, which is nice and slick. Thanks !!

Comment: and yes you are right, I will combine the best of both worlds by including [^'\''] instead of \w

Comment: @teppyogi what dbms is it? Postgres?